# Android in-memory value pairs vs. SQLite

Tags: android

What is the best way to store a large amount of value pairs if I need them during the dynamic behavior of the application? In memory (e.g. LinkedHashMap) or SQLite DB?
I have more than 4000 rows of personID and personName and I need an EditText and a Spinner. If I enter the proper personID in the EditText the Spinner should jump to the right personName, but the Spinner should contain all personsNames as well.

Currently I have implemented the "in memory" solution on the following way, because a simple array can't be larger than 64k. The code was of course generated. I've also tried to define the arrays in XML, but it also has the same limit.

```
public enum CompPeople {
    INSTANCE;

    public LinkedHashMap<Short, String> peopleIDs = new LinkedHashMap<Short, String>();

    public void initialize() {
        peopleIDs = new LinkedHashMap<Short, String>();
        setPeople1();
        setPeople2();
        setPeople3();
        setPeople4();
    }

    public void setPeople1() {
        peopleIDs.put(new Short((short) 1011), "John Doe");
        peopleIDs.put(new Short((short) 1012), "Jack Knight");
        peopleIDs.put(new Short((short) 1013), "Sue Doe");
        ...
    }

    public void setPeople2() {
        ...
    }

    public void setPeople3() {
        ...
    }

    public void setPeople4() {
        ...
    }
}
```

If the SQLite way would be better, is there a better solution to initialize a database at first run of the application than the one described here?:
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points to consider:

1. The first point of interest when deciding between a database and in-memory structures *has* to be the persistence requirements. If you need your data to remain after your application has exited, then you *will* have to use some sort of persistent storage, either that is a database or a flat file.
2. No matter how it is done, persisting objects in a database is going to be slower and, possibly, more cumbersome to program. If you can fit the objects comfortably in memory, then using a database would just be unneeded additional complexity.
3. 4000 rows is not *that* large in general, although it *might* be in the context of an embedded device if the row size is high enough due to e.g. storing blobs. How much space would you expect each row to take up? Because if we are talking about 3-4 MB, then you would *probably* be better off just using in-memory structures...